# Diferença em horas entre dias utilizando carbon

Tags: php

Ao verificar a diferença em horas entre hoje e amanhã recebo o valor de `6` que é referente a quantidade de horas até às 00:00 do dia de hoje;

```
$t = \Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow();
$n = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$n->diffInHours($t); // 6
```

Porém quando tento verificar com datas no passado recebo um numero ainda maior;

```
$y = \Carbon\Carbon::yesterday();
$n->diffInHours($n) // 41
```

Porque os valores tem essa diferença e porque a data de "ontem" tem diferença positiva maior que de amanha?

Comment: não deu certo a resposta?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic desculpe por não ter marcado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos criar um exemplo minimo, para exemplificar e mostrar o que acontece:

No primeiro resultado que é o código `print_r( \Carbon\Carbon::yesterday() );`

```
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-01-14 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

e no seu resultado que é o código: `print_r( \Carbon\Carbon::now() );`

```
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-01-15 16:51:15.992829
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

a diferença em horas desses dois resultados pelo código:

```
print_r( \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInHours( \Carbon\Carbon::yesterday() ) );
```

é o valor de **40**, porque, o primeiro resultado para chegar no dia **15** tem ***24 horas*** + ***16 horas da segunda*** é o valor de **40 horas de diferença**.

No outro que o código geral como exemplo minimo:

```
print_r( \Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow() );
print_r( \Carbon\Carbon::now() );
print_r( \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInHours( \Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow() ) );
```

***Saída:***

```
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-01-16 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-01-15 16:56:28.216548
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

tem uma diferença de 7 horas porque o dia ***15/01/2018 16:56:28.216548*** para chegar no dia ***16/01/2018*** faltam ***7 horas***.

---

[Para saber se uma data e hora é maior que a outra](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison):

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('pt_BR');

$result = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2012, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0)
            ->gt( \Carbon\Carbon::create(2012, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0) );

var_dump($result); // saída bool(false)
```

Comment: Se os resultados sempre pegaram o "menor para maior" como faço para saber quanto tempo já passou? Atualmente eu tenho um tempo em `microtime` e preciso saber se essa data que esta nesse `microtime` já passou ou não...

Comment: @RFL veja, isso que você relatou no comentário é outra coisa porém, exemplo: `microtime e preciso saber se essa data que esta nesse microtime já passou ou não` já passou onde? em relação o que?. No relato da sua pergunta está explicado o que perguntou inclusive é bem visível a diferença, mas, por favor tente colocar na sua pergunta o que precisa, e não o que o código faz somente! fico no aguardo.

Comment: quando disse "passar" me referi ao tempo mesmo...
com um microtime como posso fazer para saber se a data atual já é maior que a data do microtime.

Comment: @RFL se pode colocar isso como exemplo na sua pergunta? pra ficar como referencia!

Comment: @RFL o método para saber se uma data é maior que a outra é `gt` está editada a resposta, fiz de acordo pergunta utilizando `Carbon`