# Como pegar a diferença em horas entre duas datas utilizando o plugin Carbon, onde ele me mostre se é positivo ou negativo

Tags: php, laravel, data

Exemplo:

```
$primeiraData = Carbon::parse('2019-02-01 13:00:00');
$segundaData =   Carbon::parse('2019-02-02 14:00:00');

$resultado = $segundaData->diffInHours($primeiraData);
```

Independente da ordem que eu colocar as variáveis ele terá o mesmo resultado "25"  nesse caso.
O que preciso é que me mostre se é positivo ou negativo esse número.

Ou seja:

- do dia  2019-02-01 13:00:00   até dia 2019-02-02 14:00:00  =   + 25
- do dia  2019-02-02 14:00:00   até dia 2019-02-01 13:00:00  =  - 25

Comment: assunto relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269302/diferen%C3%A7a-em-horas-entre-dias-utilizando-carbon/269330#269330

Answer (score 1):

Olhando a documentação do Carbon, presente em:[documentação](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) na aba 'difference', caso você passe como segundo parâmetro da função diffInHours o valor false ele retorna o valor relativo. Incluindo assim o sinal de negativo caso a data passada for menor que a da instancia atual.

Segue o exemplo disponibilizado no link da documentação:

```
$dtOttawa = Carbon::createMidnightDate(2000, 1, 1, 'America/Toronto');
$dtVancouver = Carbon::createMidnightDate(2000, 1, 1, 'America/Vancouver');
echo $dtOttawa->diffInHours($dtVancouver);                             // 3
echo $dtVancouver->diffInHours($dtOttawa);                             // 3

echo $dtOttawa->diffInHours($dtVancouver, false);                      // 3
echo $dtVancouver->diffInHours($dtOttawa, false);                      // -3
```

Comment: Isso mesmo Ryan, tinha utilizado o parâmetro true, porém sem sucesso.
Obrigado pela dica, passei batido realmente lendo a documentação.

Comment: @Murilo se a resposta te ajudou marca como correta.

Comment: A resposta do Ryan está correta e meu ajudou bastante.